# Searching a list by an undefined value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, find

There is a certain list that I get after parsing a certain html page:

Could you tell me please, how can I do a search for a specific value?

Let's say I specify only part of the value `KES_` and the search should give me the entire value `KES_2023.z`.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: what did you try? You could at least use `for`-loop to work with every sublist separately. And maybe you would see that you can use another `for`-loop to work with every element on sublist.

Comment: you deleted example from question - so now it totally useless.

Comment: absolutely right. Especially after they started downvoting it without any reason, it seemed that they were downvoting the question due to some unpredictable reasons. in my opinion, the usual question is, if I did not provide any code that I tried to use, then it simply does not exist, if it had, I would have provided it. I no longer see the point in this question. I didn’t come here for an assessment, but for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your time.
I solved my little problem like this:

```
    baskets = [x for x in cols if x.count('KES_11_')]

    for line in baskets:
        line = line.rstrip('\n' + '').split(':')
        if line != ['']:
            print(line)
```

Comment: surprising idea with `count`. Most people would use `if 'KES_11_' in x`

Comment: Apparently that's why I got so many downvotes for my question :)

Comment: since in my example there are many lines in the list and so that the value that I am looking for remains without empty lines, I will adjust my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_text(list, text):
    for sublist in list:
        for string in sublist:
            if text in string:
                return string

find_text(<your-list>, "KES_11_")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be easily solved with the help of regular expression.
I am assuming that all elements of the list are of string type.

```
import re

data = ['KESL_10.1.2_Elbrus_20231206.zip', '2023-12-06 17:43', '571M', '']

term = "KESL_1"
pattern = f"[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-:]*{term}[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-:]*" # created regex to match the pattern
complete_data = "|".join(data) # joined the all elements of list to perform regex matching

print(re.findall(pattern,complete_data))
```